# Why we need ClientConfig to create a Client (using jersey)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, webclient

I am new to rest web service and trying to learn that why and where we need ClientConfig to create Client.

If someone can explain this by a simple example that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First point the ClientConfig isn't mandatory to create new Jersey client. With ClientConfig you can have some benefits:

1. You can register Filters through ClientConfigs to Jersey Client instance to use, so with Filters you can intercept the requests or responses and modify them.
2. Register provider classes,for example, that support JAXB with JSON.
3. And you can set properties to the client through ClientConfig for example,`PROPERTY_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS` to configure Jersey Client to automatically redirect to URI on 3XX HTTP response codes.

More info [here](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.9/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig.html) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with)